# Doctrine database relationship, how to relation product and product attributes

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using symfony 3.0 and doctrine orm 2.5, but I have some dificulties when relation product and product attributes.

Suppose that I have the database tables named ad *product*, *product_attribute* and *attribute*.

Firstly, each product can has many *product_attributes*.

The table *product_attribute* can be relation with many products, but has a unique attribute and value for each *product_id*.

The attribute table is really agnostic, and doesn`t know the existence of *product* and *product_attribute*, but the *product_attribute* should be a existent *attribute_id* on relation.

How can I make these? I tried to make a relationship between product and attributes using the pivot table "product_attribute", but this not persist the value of attribute...

Example of desired database structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague with no code. However if your product is persisting, that means you called the doctrine manager to persist the product. That means you are doing something like this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($product)
```

Then you may have added the product_attribute, and the attribute itself. The key to remember is that you must persist each object you want to save to the database, so something like this:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($product);
/* Add product attribute */
/* Add attribute to product attribute */
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($productAttribute);
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($attribute);
/* save to database */
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

You cannot just persist the parent object you need to persist the children to.